# How to go about checking if there are 3 of the same letter in a python string

Tags: python, string, similarity

I need to check a string from a user input and I need to know if it contains 3 of the same character e.g "!!!" or "qqq" or "111" etc.

I also need to know if the string has 3 letters next to each other on the keyboard next to each other in the string eg. "qwe" or "ert". I have no clue how to do this and must learn it.

Comment: Read this first https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I feel that there are a number of contradictory ways to interpret your requirements. Does "123AAA456" count as containing 3 of the same character? Does "1A23A4A56" count as containing 3 of the same character? Does "AAAA" count as containing 3 of the same character? Thinking about these cases may give you insight about how to approach the problem.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two different questions. I am myself trying to learn more about regex and thought it could help you.

```
import re

# https://regex101.com/r/DTrSmV/1
regex = r"(.)\1{2}" 
line = "aaa!!!oo????"
matches = re.findall(regex, line)

print(matches)
```

You could also use itertools:

```
import itertools

line = "aaa!!!oo????"
[k for k, g in itertools.groupby(line) if len(list(g)) >= 3]
```

Both return:

```
["a","!","?"]
```

---

As for the keyboard:

```
keyboard1 = "qwertyuiop"
lst = [keyboard1[ind:ind+3] for ind in range(len(keyboard1)-2)]
# lst <-- ['qwe', 'wer', 'ert', 'rty', 'tyu', 'yui', 'uio', 'iop']
```

We can use regex again and find any of the combos by compiling them:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("|".join(lst))

string = "qwengnggnrty"
re.findall(regex, string)
```

Returns

```
['qwe', 'rty']
```

## Good luck!